# cannot find "use IIS Express" in the Solution Explorer dropdown in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express, setting

I just installed VS 2013, and I cannot find an option to use IIS express when I right click on the website project name.
Did this option get moved?

Without this option when I open an existing website, and run, I get 403.14 Forbidden error saying

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

I'm new to visual studio 2013, would appreciate any help you can provide...

Answer (score 0):

Open the *Project Properties*, and go to the *Web* tab.  In the *Servers* section you should see a dropdown with three options: Local IIS, **IIS Express**, and External Host.

See [Web Servers in Visual Studio for ASP.NET Web Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This may not fix your 403 error, which is another issue.

Comment: ok, I'm in the property window, I don't see web tab, I only see website properties (I also see property page), and I don't see such option. The list of properties are "Always Start When Debugging", "Anonymous Authentication", "Manage Pipeline Mode", "SSL Enabled", "Windows Authentication".

Comment: What kind of web project is this?  For example, is it ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Just a regular small ASP.Net project